# winsock send()/recv() behavior

Tags: soap, winsock

i recently started dabbling in windows sockets by creating a simple client that would send a soap message to an existing server and then attempt to receive a response while using a blocking socket. i used the following msdn doc as my guide:
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**
it clearly states that **send()** must be followed by **shutdown()** with a SD_SEND argument before finally calling **recv()** to obtain the response. but when i attempted to execute the prescribed sequence, the **recv()** function returned a value of 0. wireshark showed that the client's request to the server was immediately followed by the same client issuing FIN and then RST before the response arrived from the server. when i ran the code in debug mode, i noticed that **send()** automatically issued FIN, and subsequent call to **shutdown(SD_SEND)** resulted in RST, which explained the 0 being returned by **recv()**. the same sequence worked, however, when i set the "keep-alive" property.
***so what i would like to know is if the call sequence described in that msdn doc for the send() function only applies to cases that involve "keep-alive" cases? and if that is the case, should the shutdown(SD_SEND) be omitted in cases that are not "keep-alive" ?***

thank you!

Comment: Well, the page you linked to doesn't say that send() must be followed by shutdown. You can call shutdown() if you don't have anything else to send on the socket again, ever - shutdown(SD_SEND) is effectivly half-closing the TCP connection(sending a FIN) The docs you point to will result in a half closed TCP session after shutdown() is called - the server needs to collaborate and understand that fact too. Are you running the code on the MSDN page, or something else ?

Comment: @nos you are correct in that shutdown() is not required. i also understand the concept of half-closed socket, as the client is no longer allowed to send any additional request. but i would still like to know why recv() returns 0 despite the doc.

Comment: Presumably because the server closed the connection. Have you programmed the server too ?

Comment: i am 100% certain that the server did not close the connection. there is no evidence of it in the wireshark and a TCP monitor i attached to the process clearly shows the response being sent by the server. it just never arrives to the client since the latter resets the connection

Comment: regardless, we can't debug it when we don't know what you're doing and what the code looks like.

Comment: the code looks exactly as it does on that msdn doc page. i just copied and pasted it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with that code. As long as the server is written to work with a half closed client, it works fine. If the server is not written to consider a half closed connection, you might observe what you're seeing though. (You also mention you're calling shutdown() several times, which you should not do).